# Using two COUNT in SELECT returns the same values

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT user_posts.id, 
   COUNT(user_post_comments.post_id) as number_of_comments,
   COUNT(user_post_reactions.post_id) as number_of_reactions

FROM user_posts

   LEFT JOIN user_post_comments
   ON (user_posts.id = user_post_comments.post_id)

   LEFT JOIN user_post_reactions
   ON (user_posts.id = user_post_reactions.post_id)
WHERE user_posts.user_id = '850e6511-2f30-472d-95a1-59a02308b46a'
group by user_posts.id
```

I have this query for getting the number of comments and reactions from another table by post_id

[current output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOQKa.png)

Comment: What is your question here? What is the result that you _expect_ to get, and how does it differ from what you are getting? Your screenshot shows that the two columns *do not* always have the same value.

Comment: Okay, so if both tables has record for the user_id I passed, it will show the same value
As you can see on my screenshot, the id 170 and 163 has the same values, that means comments and reactions table has a record for that particular user_id

But if only one of those table have that record, It will show the right result>

Comment: `count()` is an aggregate function over the  `group by user_posts.id` so that is what  it is counting, not the values in the other tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To caluclate number of comments and reactions just use subqueries. No need to join and group by.

```sql
SELECT user_posts.id, 
   ( select COUNT(*) from user_post_comments
        where user_posts.id = user_post_comments.post_id
   ) as number_of_comments,
   ( select COUNT(*) from user_post_reactions
        where user_posts.id = user_post_reactions.post_id
   ) as number_of_reactions
FROM user_posts
WHERE user_posts.user_id = '850e6511-2f30-472d-95a1-59a02308b46a'
```

Answer (score 0):

If both joins return non-null rows, what you get for each count is the product of the number of rows from each for a given user_posts.id.  One way you could fix that is by counting distinct identifiers for each table, e.g.

```
COUNT(DISTINCT user_post_comments.id) as number_of_comments
```

(Assuming "id" exists as a primary key on that table).  This may not be spectacularly efficient, but is relatively simple.

Comment: I tried using distinct like that but I don't know why it returns only 1 and 0.
I've got the expected result using the solution in top.

Thank you anyway :)

Comment: @DeltsDev Did you change the column name in the count from 'post_id' to the primary key of the other table?

Comment: Oh, I didn't noticed that you used primary key here . I tried it and it works also. Thank you

Comment: I can't upvote for now, sorry